# Rewrite jquery ajax request in axios and set xhrFields

Tags: vue.js, axios

i HAVE jquery request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://6232423.212342343.100.89:9000/api/v2/content/categories/",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
});
```

how do I make the same but in axios?
I tried like this:

```
axios.get(portal.categoriesUrl,
          {xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }}
)
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
```

see docs
https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Comment: While this code might work, it's far better to explain how or why this is a solution.