# make request in axios with credentials and data

Tags: axios

I need to make this request but in axios

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': 'en'},
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
```

I tried

```
params = {
        data: {
               'HTTP_CONTENT_LANGUAGE': 'en',
              },
        withCredentials: true
         };                
axios.post(url, params)
```

But didn't work what do I do?

Comment: Hello! And what does the server say? what is the error msg?

Comment: @LakiGeri no errors just not working something wrong with headers or data

Comment: so when you check the network in the dev-helper of browser nothing sends to the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite jquery ajax request in axios and set xhrFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589448/rewrite-jquery-ajax-request-in-axios-and-set-xhrfields)

Comment: @fatman this is not duplicate- another question is mine and I found a solution and it works but now I need to add some data params to it)

Comment: @LakiGeri it send to the server, I use this method to change language - the first with jquery changes language, one with axios not. server doesn't send errors